# How do i convert from unicode to string and write it to a file in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, compiler-errors, python-unicode

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/iit-bombay-birds-eye-view-and-quantum-biology/article18191268.ece"
htmltext = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,"lxml")

webpage_title = soup.find_all('h1', attrs = {"class": "title"})
webpage_title = webpage_title[0].get_text(strip=True)

f_obj=open("E:\\Crawler_paras_sorted_test_webpages_title.txt","w+")
file_obj.write(webpage_title)
file_obj.close
```

It gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PJM\working_extractor_sorted_title.py", line 37, in <module>
file_obj.write(webpage_title)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I fix this now ?I want it saved as string in the file.

Comment: `import io; f_obj = io.open('E:\\.........txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PJM\working_extractor_sorted_title.py", line 39, in <module>
    f_obj=open("E:\\Crawler_paras_sorted_test_webpages_title"+str(c)+".txt","w+",encoding='utf-8')
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Please read my entire comment.

Comment: sorry for the mistake...but even after inserting "io.open"..i get this error : 
             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PJM\working_extractor_sorted_title.py", line 40, in <module>
    file_obj.write(webpage_title)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Please post the contents of your `webpage_title` variable; I think it may just contain unicode escaped strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the string, which contains the unicode character point `\u2019`, try this:

```
file_obj=open("E:\\Crawler_paras_sorted_test_webpages_title.txt","w+")
file_obj.write(webpage_title.encode('utf-8'))
file_obj.close() # <-- you were missing the ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out on my own. Here is the code:

```
import urllib
import re
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/iit-bombay-birds-eye-view-and-quantum-biology/article18191268.ece"
htmltext = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,"lxml")

webpage_title = soup.find_all('h1', attrs = {"class": "title"})
webpage_title = webpage_title[0].get_text(strip=True)

with codecs.open("E:\\Crawler_paras_sorted_test_webpages_title_"+str(c)+".txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(webpage_title)
```

Codecs library really did help.

Comment: The code you wrote would not run, since there is no `file_obj`.

Answer (score -1):

Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

To solve your problem just use:
 f_obj.write(webpage_title.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))

```
In [8]: import urllib
In [8]: import re
In [9]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
In [10]: url = 'http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/iit-bombay-birds-eye-view-and-quantum-biology/article18191268.ece'

In [11]: htmltext = urllib.urlopen(url)

In [12]: soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,'lxml')

In [13]: webpage_title = soup.find_all('h1',attrs={'class':'title'})

In [14]: print webpage_title
```

[\nIIT Bombay: Bird\u2019s eye view and quantum biology\n]

```
In [15]: webpage_title = webpage_title[0].get_text(strip=True)

In [16]: print webpage_title
```

IIT Bombay: Bird’s eye view and quantum biology

```
In [17]: f_obj = open('Crawler_paras_sorted_test_webpages_title.txt', 'w')
```

### In [18]: f_obj.write(webpage_title)

UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 f_obj.write(webpage_title)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

```
In [19]: f_obj.write(webpage_title.encode("utf8"))

In [21]: f_obj.close()
```

ok,sovle this using:
    webpages_title.encode("utf8")

Comment: The only problem is that the actual title is: `IIT Bombay: Bird’s eye view and quantum biology`